# Firebase value not updating

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everything is working fine, I think just `userDataModel.setUserRating(aFloat / (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());` is not giving value.

And `String.valueof(aFloat / (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));`
Is also giving the correct value.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userDataModel.getUserID()).child("Ratings")
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    userDataModel1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDataModel.class);
                                    aFloat = aFloat + Float.parseFloat(Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot1.getValue()).toString());
                                }
                                userDataModel.setUserRating(aFloat / (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
```

UserDataModel

```
public class UserDataModel {
    float userRating;

    public float getUserRating() {
        return userRating;
    }

    public void setUserRating(float userRating) {
        this.userRating = userRating;
    }
}
```

Image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t14Cc.png

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: In cannot see any `Ratings` child in your database.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt3MB.png  @AlexMamo now look here

Comment: Log the values of `aFloat` and `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`. That's a good debugging first step.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening maybe because `userDataModel.setUserRating(aFloat / (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());` is returning null so you don't get a value

Comment: No ```String.valueof(aFloat / (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));``` is giving correct value

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: I don't know. That's what I also asked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code us the fact that your `UserDataModel` has a field named `userRating`, while in your database the property is actually a `uid`. This property is dynamic, so you cannot use a POJO class for that. If you want to get the values of those ratings, please try this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ratingsRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("Ratings");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double rating = ds.getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", "rating: " + rating);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
ratingsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be values of all ratings that exist within the `Ratings` node.

```
3.5
2
```

Now, you can simply make the average or whatever you need with those values.

Comment: Oh, I saw the real problem right now. I'll edit my answer right away.

Comment: Please check my edited answer and tell me if it wroks.